# How to do an identification request for custom art

Tags: support, identification-questions

I want to identify characters from a piece of physical art I purchased.  By taking a photo of it, Google Image search correctly identifies is a Totoro bus stop parody, but I cannot find it on this [List of Totoro Bus Stop Parodies](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/totoro-bus-stop-parodies/photos/sort/oldest).  The image is signed "Payer 2008" but I cannot find a DeviantArt site for "Payer" and I cannot find them on various searches involving "Payer" and "Totoro".

I see that identification requests are banned, and I have read the meta posts on it.  My identification request does not seem to fit.  It is not directly from any individual anime or manga, it is not digital so I can't search for an exact match.  Yet I dare not post it using that tag, and I dare not post it without using the tag since that would be disingenuous.

How can I ask this question on the network?

Comment: first of all, you don't ask it on StackOverflow. Second, if you have a picture of your physical art, you can ask it using [tag:merchandise] tag (note that you can only ask if you have the picture physically, if it's digital custom art, it's off-topic), add detail like where you bought it and everything that can help us finding what you want, but only if that art is related to anime, otherwise, you can try SciFi.SE or Movie.SE

Comment: Sorry, I meant stackexchange.  You can tell where I spend most of my time. :)

Comment: @Darjeeling:  It's a parody though.  I'm not sure if merchandise would accurately cover parodies.